# copy entire row instead of only one field

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone please advise as to what is wrong in my coding. It past only one filed i.e column 'A' instead of entire row. I want to copy the seleted row and past in other file..

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rlastrow As Long
Dim rr As Range

Dim myFileNameDir1 As String
Dim zz As Integer
Dim Irow As Range

myFileNameDir1 = Sheet3.Range("V7").Value
Workbooks.Open fileName:=myFileNameDir1, UpdateLinks:=0
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Tracker")
str = ListView6.SelectedItem
Set match = ws1.Cells.Find(str)
LastRow = ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count


With ws1
     .AutoFilterMode = False
     IRow1 = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     With .Range("A1:A" & IRow1)
          .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=str
          .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A" & LastRow + 1)

     End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False

End With
```

Comment: try using `.entirerow` in your copy line

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A" & LastRow + 1)
```

To

```
.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A" & LastRow + 1)
```